# IntelliJ terminal resized by project tree view

Tags: intellij-idea

For some reason the terminal on my IntelliJ does not go the full width of my IDE's window when the project tree view is open. I have never overwritten the default layout, however performing a layout restore to default doesn't fix this.

This is what it currently looks like:

[image: terminal is being resized by project tree view]

[image: docked and pinned project view]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disable the **Widescreen tool window layout** option:

[image: Widescreen tool window layout]

Comment: I have no clue how I managed to get this setting changed. Would never have occured to me to look in there. Thanks!